# CSS problems with google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

Why am I having problems with css in google chrome? I downloaded a bootstrap theme, copy pasted everything, everything works perfect in every browser (firefox, edge, IE, safary) except in google chrome (same problems in opera, but not a big problem).

I will show some code and screenshots.

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Reports" asp-action="Index">Online Report Manager</a>
        </div>

        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
```

How it appears in Firefox

[image]

How in Chrome

[image]

So there is some extra space in chrome and the search icon is smaller!

A popup dialog error:

The code:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
        $(".dialogOnResize").css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '50%', 'margin-top': '-110px', 'left': '50%', 'margin-left': '-165px' });
    });

    dialogDiv.dialog({
        title: "Confirm Delete",
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        minWidth: 340,
        minHeight: 220,
        create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '50%', 'margin-top': '-110px', 'left': '50%', 'margin-left': '-165px' }).addClass('dialogOnResize'); },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
        },
        buttons: {
```

In Firefox (Larger screens)
[image]

In Firefox (smaller screen, phone screen size)
[image]

It appears in the center.

Same code for Chrome (Large screen)
[image]

It's not in the center of the window, but in the center of the document, so if there are more records in the datatable, the popup will go down and down till lost of sight.

Now same scenario with Chrome in small screen (phone size), when I startup the project in small size
[image]

It is also supposed to stay in center while I scroll up/down, which in this case doesn't, it stays there, out of sight.

But if I drag the window corner and change the size just by 1px (it gets fixed):
[image]

Also by changing the screen size (from big to small) after the project startup in big size, the popup follows the center of the screen. So in chrome, the popup aligns where it should only after the browser size is changed.

Comment: [This question is off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: "I am posting no code." - is why I will down vote and vote to close.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. "

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith if you want to post the entire project html css and js then I post code

Comment: If you want to be more specific, then be specific, however posting your whole page in a code dump will return the same results

Comment: It's 100% the same code from the template I downloaded, the template code works on chrome, but when I copy paste it in my project, it doesn't work well in chrome. Hey, even IE can make it work how it's supposed

Comment: Did you try to delete cache in Chrome or load the page in Incognito mode?

Comment: WHAT IS NOT WORKING?!

Comment: Refresh the page by pressing CTRL+F5 see if that does it for you

Comment: alignments, effects, responses to user, lot of things. example: dialog popup doesn't appear in the center of the screen (window), but in the center of the page content. Divs are strange looking, with extra margin, or different sizes. The list goes on

Comment: Refresh the page by pressing CTRL+F5 I feel like a broken record

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I tried ctrl+f5, cleaning cookies and everything. It's just things are getting different in chrome

Comment: That is too bad... Also too bad that this question has not been put on hold yet...

Comment: I don't know why this question is a big problem... it's not also the only project I am getting problems with google chrome... I'm not a designer or front-end dev to know where the problem is and how to fix it, that's why I asked, to get help, and not to tell if this a good question or not

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith other problem, I have this popup dialog issue, making it appear who knows where, but when I change the browser size, by just 1px it goes where it should!

Comment: Start with the pop up, paste your code for the pop up.

Comment: Here or should I start an other thread?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith here I added the code for the errors in this project (till now).. in other project I have also problems when I implement bootstrap templates

Comment: @Arianit, it seems as though you think SO is a free debugging service. Hint: it's not. It's *your* job to post questions that meet the gudelines of this site. If you disagree with the gudelines, then  you should feel free to abstain from participating in this community. Otherwise, if you feel that you *do* have a question worth answering, I recommend reading [ask], and updating your question to include a [mcve], with additional emphasis on **minimal**. Use a stack snippet or jsfiddle or codepen to reproduce the issue and get rid of everything else that's not relevant from the question.

Comment: @zzzzBov I think my question was very clear. I wanted to know what is different in chrome than in other browsers, what should I consider in the future to avoid these problems. I wanted an overview in a developer perspective, not to know which browser to use, but how to make things work for every browser. For me it's a big problem, same code, same everything not working in chrome, is nothing to close an eye to.

Comment: Once people complain why there is no code, and now they complain why there is code!!!

Comment: @Arianit, "but how to make things work for every browser" hah! nearly made me do a spit-take. I suppose I shouldn't have been surprised as you'd already admitted to not being a front-end developer, but *this is front-end development*. Browsers run different code and will have differences. That's why [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) exists; that's why there are so many [tag:css] questions. If you want a comprehensive list, then this question is too broad. There are too many browser inconsistencies to count.

Comment: @zzzzBov but why does this exact code work from the template, and the same code from my project doesn't work?? SAME CODE

Comment: @Arianit, you still haven't included a [mcve], let me know when you've added it and i'll take a look.

Comment: @zzzzBov you didn't even bother to look

Comment: this is the best I can do, I can't minify it more, there are simple samples and screenshots that are showing the errors

Comment: @Arianit, it's obvious to me that you didn't even bother to read the [mcve] page. Screenshots alone are worthless. You need to provide an example that replicates the behavior, which would include HTML & CSS, and maybe a screenshot of what your expected result is. As it is you've posted a bunch of images, some unrelated JS, and a small bit of HTML, none of which replicates the issue you're running into. It seems that you expect an answer to be handed to you, so I'm done attempting to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have different implementations of the HTML spec, each slightly different and none perfectly conforming to the standards. That's why websites sometimes look different in different browsers. You can use a site like www.caniuse.com or the MDN to see browser support for different features.

Comment: but the template I got works fine, but in my project I'm having problems with chrome!! It's exactly the same code, no changes in .css or .js files.

Comment: It will be very hard to help you without some idea of what the code is. There could be a lot of reasons why things are different.

Comment: @Arianit: this answer is as specific as any can be without details about the problems you're seeing.

Comment: But isn't google chrome supposed to support everything, isn't it the "best" browser? Why does it make the divs look different, bigger, smaller, not how they should, more space between elements. Everything work fine in every other browser, making me happy for the design and stuff I did, but when I test the app in chrome!!! Where should I start to complain